# [PHP-Ajax]Multiple Ajax calls are not parallel plus browser does not change page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, xampp

thanks in advance for your userful replies and support.

I'm developing a simple website based on PHP, JS and SQL Server Express.

**The problem is:**

It seems that the each ajax call needs to wait the response of the previous one before running and displaying the results. Below you can see the timings from Chrome console:

[image]

As you can see the TTFB is very huge.

Another strange thing is that if I want to change page clicking on a menu link, the browser will wait the end of all ajax requests before executing the page change request.
Reading in other SO posts, this is because of session_start() and session_write_close(); .
So in the php file that controls the login and the creation of session info (that are non changed anymore after the login) I wrote these instructions but the problem still occurs:

```
// Allow only verified user
if($email_signin == $email && $password_signin == $password) {
                    session_start();
                    header("Location: index.php");
                    $_SESSION['nameLast'] = $name;
                    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                    $_SESSION['oe'] = $oe;
                    $_SESSION['admin'] = $isAdmin;
                    $_SESSION['logged'] = true;
                    $_SESSION['root'] = str_replace('C:\\xampp\\apps\\','/', realpath(dirname(__DIR__).'/../../'));
                    session_write_close();}
```

On the homepage i'm calling 6 ajax requests that perform an SQL query and then display the results using chart.js.
This is the general function that i call from index.php (the functions are include into a .js file):

```
    function getProductInfo(admin, oe, email, productClass, productName, url){
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'get',
        data: {
            admin: admin,
            oe: oe,
            email: email
          },
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(response) {
            generateChart(response, productClass, productName);
        }
    });
}

function generateChart(response, productClass, productName){
    var label = [];
    var data = [];
    
    $.each(response, function(index, obj) {
            label.push(obj.CountryCode);
            data.push(obj.ProductCount);
    }) 
    
    if(response.length > 0){
    $(productClass).show();
    var option = {
        legend: {
            display: false
            },
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Concurrent '+productName+' instances',
                fontSize: 16,
                fontColor: '#006192'
            },
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    display: true,
                    ticks: {
                    min: 0,
                    stepSize: 1,
                    max: Math.max.apply(Math, data) + 3
                    }
                }]
            }
    }

    var chartData = {
      labels: label,
      datasets: [{
          label: productName,
          data: data,
          backgroundColor: getRandomColor
          }]
    };

    var canvas = document.getElementById(productClass);
    var radarBar = new Chart(canvas, {
      type: "bar",
      data: chartData,
      options: option
    });
    }}
```

This is, instead, where i call the function getProductInfo from index.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/generateChart.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var admin = <?php echo $_SESSION['admin']?>;
    var oe = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['oe']);?>;
    var email = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['email']);?>;
    getProductInfo(admin, oe, email, '.radarB', 'Radar Base', 'src/stats/radarBase.php');
    getProductInfo(admin, oe, email, '.emblem', 'Emblem', 'src/stats/emblem.php');
    getProductInfo(admin, oe, email, '.emblemXE', 'Emblem XE', 'src/stats/emblemXE.php');
    getProductInfo(admin, oe, email, '.radarC', 'Radar Classifier', 'src/stats/radarClassifier.php');
    getProductOE();
    generateUserTable(admin, oe, email);
</script>
```

This is one of the SQL query performed (for Emblem XE, RadarB and Radar C the query is the same):

```
$emblem_sql = " SELECT a.CountryCode, a.ProductName, COUNT(*) as ProductCount
                    FROM
                    (
                    SELECT DISTINCT t.UserName AS UserName, Name, CountryCode, ProductName, SnapshotDate, ue.Domain FROM [dbo].[LicenseSrvSnapshot] t 
                                                 INNER JOIN [dbo].[Ref_Users] ue ON ue.UserName = t.Username 
                                                 WHERE  SnapshotDate >= dateadd(minute, -5, getdate()) AND ProductName = 'Emblem'
                                                   ) as a
                    GROUP BY CountryCode, ProductName";
```

I started to think that the problem is on server-side instead of browser/php/js configuration.
The server is on XAMPP and i'm using SQL server Express as database.
XAMPP has the default configuration and i've just enabled MPM but actually I don't know which is the type of MPM used (pre-fork, worker).

Finally, I don't know why, the browser refreshs the page each 6-10 min by itself.

I hope that i've made the problem quite clear and included all the needed info.

Comment: Did you check your SQL statements' efficiency, for example with EXPLAIN? Did you measure how long PHP scripts run? Depending on your PHP environment it can happen that every script has to be completed before the next one is started (synchronous). But 6 seconds seem to be high anyway.

Comment: could u try remove the ajax `type:'get'` (default ist 'GET') and why do you parametrize through the js if u have the values in $_SESSION anyway? This way i could just call `getProductInfo(true ..` from client-side and "i´m admin"

Comment: @PeterKoltai could you please be more clear? if you can link me a guide or write any steps to be performed i would very happy to execute them. Could be possible that database SQL Server Express runs each sql request not in parallel?

Comment: @johnSmith you're right. i've updated my code and now i removed the arguments (email, admin and oe) because I can retrieve them direclty from the session. Do I need to edit also the original post?

Comment: @DavideCasillo I don' know your SQL server but in MySQL for example `EXPLAIN SELECT...` gives you information about how efficient is your query, search for how you can do it in SQL Server Express and how to interpret the results. This will tell you whether you have a database problem or not.

Comment: @DavideCasillo Another issue can be that the database connection is created every time when you execute a script. Depending on many factors it can be useful the have persistent connections, once again, search for it, there is many information available.